# Hide the checkboxes of every card of a SharePoint List in Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I have a SharePoint List with the Gallery view. I am customizing the view in JSON.

What I would like is to hide the checkbox of every card. I have tried but no luck.

Is that even possible? Even go to the settings and uncheck the display of the checkbox. But it did not work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to remove the checkbox:

1. Go to your SharePoint list and open gallery view.
2. Click on "Switch view options" drop down from top right corner > select "Format current view":

   [image]
3. Click on "Edit card" link below Card Designer:

   [image]
4. Choose the columns you want to show/hide and other options as per your requirements. Then select "Advanced mode" link (without clicking Save button):

   [image]
5. Change `hideSelection` to `true` and then click "Save" button:

   [image]

---

**Output**:

Checkbox is now hidden in gallery view:

[image]