# How to center the content of all the SharePoint Gallery cards?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

How can I center the content of all the SharePoint Gallery cards?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Follow my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308834/hide-the-checkboxes-of-every-card-of-a-sharepoint-list-in-gallery-view) up to step #4 to enter into advanced mode in gallery view formatting.
2. Then add below styling to top/outer most `div` element in the JSON:

```
"style":{
    "text-align": "center"
},
```

**Output**:

[image]

If any column value is not aligned to center automatically, locate the code used in same JSON for that particular column and then add `"text-align": "center"` styling to nested elements wherever required.

Comment: Thanks only the profile picture doesn't align.  I have tried this below but no luck:

Comment: "style": {
                      "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'none', '')",
                      "width": "72px",
                      "height": "72px",
                      "align": "center"
                    },

Comment: Are you showing person column and their profile picture in gallery view?

Comment: Yes i have a person column with the profile picture in gallery view :)

Comment: Try `”align-content”: ”center”` or `”align-items”: ”center”` or `”text-align”: ”center”`. Also, are you adding it for img element or div element?

Comment: I found the problem :) The Problem was Display: flex and i change it to: Display;inline-block